# OBJ Model Renderering Gaps

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, wavefront

When I render a OBJ Wavefront model which I parse using a parser that I built myself, I get the following result when rendering:

[image]

Are the gaps that are present normal or is it just from faulty rendering code?

Here is the rendering code:

```
glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glScaled(scale, scale, scale);

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

for (int i = 0; i < vertices_indexes.size()-3; i+=3) {
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        if (is_normals) glNormal3f(normals.at(normals_indexes[i]).x, normals.at(normals_indexes[i]).y, normals.at(normals_indexes[i]).z);
        glVertex3f(vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i]).x, vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i]).y, vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i]).z);

        if (is_normals) glNormal3f(normals.at(normals_indexes[i+1]).x, normals.at(normals_indexes[i+1]).y, normals.at(normals_indexes[i+1]).z);
        glVertex3f(vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i + 1]).x, vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i + 1]).y, vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i + 1]).z);

        if (is_normals) glNormal3f(normals.at(normals_indexes[i+2]).x, normals.at(normals_indexes[i+2]).y, normals.at(normals_indexes[i+2]).z);
        glVertex3f(vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i + 2]).x, vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i + 2]).y, vertices.at(vertices_indexes[i + 2]).z);
    glEnd();
}

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Could you please indicate the topology of the model produced by your parser.

Comment: Make sure you subtract 1 from each indices.  Wavefront files have indices that start with 1, but OpenGL starts counting from 0.

Comment: Your vertex/index data seems to be OK, but it looks like triangle culling. Try to render the same scene without backface culling and check if the holes disappeared.

Comment: @kolenda It's probably not culling, or we would see the triangles on the other side of the ball. My guess is that the OBJ contains quads, not triangles... i.e. the parser is faulty, not the renderer.

Comment: @Calvin1602 You may be right but without lighting and texture you can't distinguish between front and back triangles :)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - are you sure GL_TRIANGLE_FAN is appropriate? E.g. an OBJ could specify data as quads, and you'd need to process this to get it as a triangle fan. Perhaps posting your parser would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that your model is created with triangles and not quads? Most models you find will come rendered in quads by default, so you can either load it up in a 3D program (like Blender or Maya) and convert the mesh to triangles (Ctrl+T in Blender), or change your parser to handle quads.